# why i get the error message doubled/tripled... if i give more than 1 characters

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am trying writing a code that reads from stdin of the user and also  check the input if it is an integer or not.

this is my function:

```
 int Test(int *integer)
 {
    int input = *integer;
    int check; 

    do
    {
      check = scanf("%d", &input);

      if(check == 1) // return value should be 1
      {
        *integer= input;
        break;

      }
      else
      {
        printf("Error Message")
      }

      }while(check!=1 && getchar() != '\n');
      return 0;


    }
```

main:

```
  int digit = 0;

  Test(&digit);
```

if I enter for example "a" it just gives me 1 of the "Error message" and ask me to enter again but if i enter "fooooo" it gives me 5 or more error messages and then ask me to enter again. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What is `zahl`?

Comment: is Intger from function parameter sorry had it wrong

Comment: OK, what's happening here is that any non-integer input is being left behind in the input buffer after an unsuccessful read at `scanf("%d", &input)`. You're gradually consuming these characters at the end of the `do...while` loop (with the call to `getchar()`), but until they've all gone, you'll still trying to read them with the `scanf()` statement.

Comment: Look at what it's doing when `scanf` fails to parse an integer:  It goes to the bottom, consumes one of the garbage characters (e.g. 'f' or 'o'), it loops back, fails to parse an integer, consumes one more garbage character, etc. etc.

Comment: ahh thats why! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your program simply doing this:

```
else {
    printf("Error Message");
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}
```

The reason your code failed: If the input is not a number, the conversion will be interrupted and there are characters left in the buffer. The next round will consume one character at a time until there are none left.

The while loop above will read from the buffer until a newline and thus, effectively empty the buffer from unwanted characters.

Comment: Thanks alot!! yeah it was really confusing at first sight but now it makes sense!